# When to override ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and it's currently not clear whether I need to override the `OnActionExecutingAsync()` method. This is a project that uses ASP.NET WebAPI v5.2.3.

I've currently overridden both `OnActionExecuting()` and `OnActionExecutingAsync()`, where both methods call the same private method that does the actual work of the filter.

What I find is that *both* methods are getting called - first `OnActionExecutingAsync()` and then - from within the call to `base.OnActionExecutingAsync()` - `OnActionExecuting()` gets called.

So do I only need to override `OnActionExecuting()`? If so, when would I ever need to override the async version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll run into problems trying to use `OnActionExecuting` on an async controller because it won't be able to communicate the `CancellationToken` that the system uses to manage threads. You might find that `OnActionExecuting` fires on resumption of an action after an `await`, which might be a problem depending on what your filter is expecting, for example.

Based on some experimentation though, it appears that `OnActionExecutingAsync` works fine with non-async controllers.

Answer (score 0):

> So do I only need to override OnActionExecuting()? If so, when would I ever need to override the async version?

Only if you have a long running task in your filter.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when ever a method has an async version and a sync version both of them will call and you should just override or hook to one of them. For this case, you could check it in [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/44048331e936de39073ca5eab97bd5b5cdb0a0f2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L339) link

```
    [NonAction]
    public virtual async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (next == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        }

        OnActionExecuting(context);
        if (context.Result == null)
        {
            OnActionExecuted(await next());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please paste the answer here and use links for reference only as it may change.

Comment: In fact, the question is not asking for a sample code but I have added the code as you want.